# Setting NFS Domain name on Windows 2012 NFS Server

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2012, windows, nfs4

I have a Windows 2012 NFS server setup to use my AD domain as an authentication source. My domain is ad.example.com with a NetBIOS name of AD. My linux machines have idmapd configured to use ad.example.com as the domain. When I `ls -al` my folders I get all the user and groups returning as nobody. I tracked it down and I realized that the Windows NFS Server is sending the NFS domain as AD. How do I configure the Windows NFS server to use ad.example.com as the NFS domain so my NFS client can negotiate the uids correctly?

Comment: you can configure your client to use the same domain: General->Domain in /etc/idmapd.conf

Comment: I'm running a NexentaStor box that is using IDMU and I need to have the domain configured as ad.example.com. So it's not really easy to change my entire domain.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem: My Server is reporting the domain name (Kerberos realm) instead of the FQDN. Did you ever find out how to fix that on the server side?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( I even tried asking on the MSDN forums http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/148b51a2-9fc7-4262-ac3f-5cd2a8756c48/nfs41-returning-incorrect-principal-on-ls?forum=winserver8gen#148b51a2-9fc7-4262-ac3f-5cd2a8756c48